# Is there a way to view Assembly File?

Tags: swift, xcode, assembly, xcode6, xcode7

In `Xcode 4` I could see the assembly file by clicking on `Product\Generate Output\Assembly File`.

But in Xcode 6 and 7 I do not see that option for a `Swift` file.

Is this feature removed or where do I find it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Xcode 6 and Xcode 7 (up to the current Xcode 7.3) do not offer the option to view the generated assembly file
for *Swift* input. (Perhaps that feature will be added in a later
release.)

Currently the only way that I know of is to call the compiler on the command line
with the "-emit-assembly" option, e.g.

```
xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc -emit-assembly main.swift
```

Comment: how to emit assembly for ARM platform？

Answer (score 7):

This only works for pure Swift, but a nice swift assembler is online here: https://swift.godbolt.org. It even color-codes different sections so you can see which lines the assembly comes from.

Answer (score 6):

## Partial Assembly View

You can profile your application using **Instruments** (`Cmd+I` from Xcode) with *Time Profiler* template. When you find the part that interests you (eg. your critical loop), double click the `Symbol Name` and in the upper right corner select `View Disassembly` or `Show side-by-side source/disassembly views` to see the assembly.

From the gear icon in the same corner, you can `Show ISA Reference Guide`.